# Question became irrelevant

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question 6 months ago, not long after questioning, I tried a completely different alternative, which worked perfectly, thus making the question irrelevant.

I don't have the source code for the question, so I don't know if the answer given is correct, how should I proceed?

Comment: The older question is not suddenly irrelevant because *you* have opted for another way - some people could still prefer/need the first one. I say don't delete. If you can't judge the quality of the answer, then just don't. Other users will vote accordingly.

Comment: @EricAya nice answer ;)

Comment: @EricAya ^ That

Comment: Is there a way to give up the right to decide if the answer is the correct one or not? Since I can't judge it, I shouldn't be the one to decide that

Comment: @Guedez Then don't accept an answer, it's that easy.

Comment: Sounds to me that you actually have an answer to that question.  "Don't do it that way, do it *this* way instead" is a perfectly good answer.  You are not the first SO user that tried to solve a problem the wrong way.  Just about all of them do :)  So you should post that answer of course.  And accept it as the answer to close your question.

Comment: It's not about the right or wrong way to do it, I just didn't want to bother with learning something so complicated as that, it was faster to do by hand in Netty. Same way I didn't bother learning how to enable websocket https on netty because it seemed complicated to get the certificates running, so I just implemented it by hand with forgejs (not even https, just some asymmetric handshake to share a symmetric key to encrypt everything that comes after).

The question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480731. "Use netty instead" is not an answer to that

Comment: @Guedez: I'm asking myself the very same question at the moment. My question doesn't have any answers, yet, and it is unlikely that it will. I've gone a different way altogether and used a different DB engine, which got me out of trouble.